# SoftInputMode = "adjustResize" Does not scroll page content when content height is less than display height when virtual keyboard pops up

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard, cordova-android

I am using Cordova to render my website in mobile. And I have the below config in manifest.xml to adjust resize the screen when virtual keyboard pops up.

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

It works fine (as in the image below) when the web page content exceeds the screen size. The contents are scrolled up so that the text box and submit button are visible above the keyboard.

[image]

But when the page content height is less than that of the screen, then the page contents are not scrolled and the virtual keyboard pops up hiding the content behind. In the below image, the submit button is hidden behind the virtual keyboard.

[image]

What config should I update so that the contents are scrolled irrespective of the content height?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SoftInputMode to "adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem, and thanks to your detailed description I found a workaround:  In your CSS, set the `height` of your page content to `calc(100% + 1px)`.  This causes the content to correctly scroll up when the soft keyboard is activated.

Side note: setting `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` (as suggested here and elsewhere) made no difference for me, even when using `edit-config` in `config.xml` to make it correctly transfer to AndroidManifest.xml .